# Scaling sprites (not textures) for target viewport size/device in MonoGame

Tags: xna, scaling, monogame

When you have to display a series of visual components (sprites) within the context of a game each taking a literal height and width that needs to be relative to the height & width of the Viewport (not necessarily aspect ratio) of the target device:

- Is there a scaling class to help come up with scaling ratio in a dynamic fashion based on current device viewport size?
- Will I need to roll my own scaling ratio algorithm?
- Any cross platform issues I should be aware of?

*This is not a question relating to the loading of assets based on target device nor is it a question of how to perform the scaling of the sprite (which is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194913.aspx), rather a question of how to determine the scale of sprites based on view port size.*

Comment: Scale of what sprites, of what size, compared to what in how big a viewport? An example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create your own implementation of scaling.

For example, the default target viewport dimensions are:

```
const int defaultWidth = 1280, defaultHeight = 720;
```

And your current screen dimensions are `800×600`, which gives you a (let's use a `Vector2` instead of two floats):

```
int currentWidth  = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
    currentHeight = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;

Vector2 scale = new Vector2(currentWidth  / defaultWidth,
                            currentHeight / defaultHeight);
```

This gives you a `{0.625; 0.83333}`. You can now use this in a handy `SpriteBatch.Draw()` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb196420%28v=xnagamestudio%29.aspx) that takes a `Vector2` scaling variable:

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     Vector2 scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
)
```

Alternatively, you can draw all your stuff to a `RenderTarget2D` and copy the resulting image from there to a stretched texture on the main screen, but that will still require the above `SpriteBatch.Draw()` overload, though it might save you time if you have lots of draw calls.

Comment: This is the correct answer for sure, but for my needs it falls short in that the scaling messed with the tap gesture detection (not mentioned in question).  My answer resolved my problems in a very simple way, but I understand it may not be the cleanest solution going forward.  That is why I marked this as correct answer.

Comment: HI,I have used these codes,could you please tell me how can i scale touch input after this....

Comment: @uncle_scrooge if you want an answer to a different question, you should either find such a question or ask it, not post a comment.

Comment: this is not an different question...its completely related to this.after scaling inputs will not work..you know this...

Comment: anyways probably u have done something to ur touch input...by the way i already created a question regarding this before two days ago....Pls answer if u want..below is the link..

Comment: I'm not using touch input at all. My XNA coding was limited to PC only, so no, I don't know and I can't help you with touch input. Your question may or may not be be related, but it is not the same question. Otherwise you'd find an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Another Option to generate the scale would be to leverage:

```
var scaleMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(
           (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / View.Width,
           (float)GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / View.Width, 1f);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb195692.aspx.

But this did not meet my needs, as I would then have to roll my own transform to map touch input location to the 'transformed' sprites (which respond to user touch input by knowing their own position and size).

In the end I used a **percentage based approach.**

I basically got the viewport height and width...

```
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width  
GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height
```

...then calculated the Height and Width of my sprites (Note: "as mentioned in question they take a literal height and width") based on their relative size to the screen myself using percentages.

```
//I want the buttons height and width to be 20% of the viewport 
var x, y = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.2f; //20% of screen width
var btnsize = new Vector(x,y);
var button = new GameButton(btnsize);
```

Then once I have the size of the button I am able to calculate the position on the screen to render the button based of the size of the button and the available viewport size, against working in relative position based in percentages.